# SwiftUI: Generic parameter 'Subject' could not be inferred

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift5, combine

I built a `LoadingView` with SwiftUI for showing some loading stuff in my app while I'm fetching remote data from an API. I am on Xcode Version 11.0 beta 5.

This is the `LoadingView`:

```
struct LoadingView<Content>: View where Content: View {

    @Binding var isShowing: Bool
    var content: () -> Content

    var body: some View {

        GeometryReader { geometry in

            ZStack(alignment: .center) {

                self.content()
                    .disabled(self.isShowing)
                    .blur(radius: self.isShowing ? 3 : 0)

                VStack {
                    Text("Loading...")
                    ActivityIndicator(isAnimating: .constant(true), style: .large)
                }
                .frame(width: geometry.size.width / 2,
                       height: geometry.size.height / 5)
                    .background(Color.white)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.primary)
                    .cornerRadius(5)
                    .opacity(self.isShowing ? 1 : 0)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is my DataStore. It is declared as `ObservableObject` and has more than one `@Published` property. Also it does some remote fetching from an API:

```
class CharacterStore: ObservableObject {

    @Published private(set) var isLoading = false


    // Fetches some stuff from a remote api
    func fetch() {

        self.isLoading = true

        myService.getCharacters { (result) in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.isLoading = false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And finally this is the View I want to show my `LoadingView` with the content of `ContentView` in it. Of course I am setting the `@EnvironmentObject` before showing this view.

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var charStore: CharacterStore

    var body: some View {

        LoadingView(isShowing: self.$charStore.isLoading) { // Here I get the error

            // Show some Content here
            Text("")
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that I want to bind `self.$charStore.isLoading` to `LoadingView`. In this line i get the following error:

> Generic parameter 'Subject' could not be inferred

I tried in several ways but none of these things work. Btw: If I use a `@State` property in `ContentView` it just works fine like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var charStore: CharacterStore

    @State var loads: Bool = false

    var body: some View {

        LoadingView(isShowing: self.$loads) { // Here I get no error

            // Show some Content here
            Text("")
        }
    }
}
```

Am I missing a thing? If you need further informations let me know i can provide more content if needed.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since your `LoadingView` is not going to modify .isLoading, you do not need to pass it as a binding:

```swift
LoadingView(isShowing: self.$charStore.isLoading)
```

Instead, remove the `@Binding` in `LoadingView`:

```swift
struct LoadingView<Content>: View where Content: View {

    var isShowing: Bool
    ...
```

and create it like this (remove the dollar sign):

```swift
LoadingView(isShowing: self.charStore.isLoading) { ... }
```

On the contrary, if you insist on passing a binding, then you need to remove the `private(set)` from:

```swift
@Published private(set) var isLoading = false
```

Comment: Both ways are working. I decided to go for solution 1: Remove the @Binding from isShowing in LoadingView is fine since for my case LoadingView doesn't need to modifiy the loadingState. Thanks for you help!

Comment: For future Googlers coming across this, a `Binding` needs to have access to both the setter and getter of a projected property.  I had this issue where I was trying to map a computed property (which was get-only) onto a `Binding` parameter as here.  This can be worked around, but it turned out my computed property needed a setter anyway.  Adding one fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score -1):

Couldn't you do the following:

Replacing the @Binding by the same @EnvironmentObject as the ContentView uses.

```swift
struct LoadingView<Content>: View where Content: View {
    @EnvirontmentObject var charStore: CharacterStore // added
    //@Binding var isShowing: Bool // removed
    var content: () -> Content

    var body: some View {

        GeometryReader { geometry in

            ZStack(alignment: .center) {

                self.content()
                    .disabled(self.$charStore.isLoading) // Changed
                    .blur(radius: self.$charStore.isLoading ? 3 : 0) // Changed

                VStack {
                    Text("Loading...")
                    ActivityIndicator(isAnimating: .constant(true), style: .large)
                }
                .frame(width: geometry.size.width / 2,
                       height: geometry.size.height / 5)
                    .background(Color.white)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.primary)
                    .cornerRadius(5)
                    .opacity(self.$charStore.isLoading ? 1 : 0) // Changed
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, you also have to remove the isShowing parameter from the LoadingView() initializer in the ContentView.

Please correct me if I am wrong!

Comment: I will try it out later and let you know: The issue with your solution is that, of course, I want to add the LoadingView not only in combination with my charStore ... it should be a generic LoadingView, which i can use anywhere i want to.